# Get parent of a node referenced by SKReferenceNode in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I'm using Xcode's Scene Editor to build a `GameScene`.

1. In the `GameScene.sks` file, I have added an `SKReferenceNode` that I named `componentReference`. This reference node references `Component` which represents the file `Component.sks`. `Component.sks` contains nothing but a single `SKSpriteNode` named `component`.
2. Everything shows up fine on my screen when I build the app. I do see `Component` on my screen in exactly the same way I've defined it in `Component.sks`.
3. In `GameScene.swift`, I can successfully get a pointer to `component` by calling this: `let component = childNode(withName:"//component")`. However, when I try to get the parent of `component` using
   `component.parent`, `nil` gets returned.
4. My question is: what happens to reference nodes when the app starts running and "resolves" them as the Apple reference docs mention? Why do the reference nodes stick around? I'd expect the node a reference node is referencing to be added to the scene, and thus the node's parent to be the scene. For example, in this case, I'd expect `component` to have `GameScene` as its parent. But in actual fact, `component` doesn't have a parent, whereas `componentReference` still exists and has `GameScene` as its parent.

Comment: too broad,  Since you are using SKReferenceNode, I am assuming this is all built via the SpriteKit builder (there is no reason to use SKReferenceNode otherwise).  So where are you checking if b's parent is nil?  B is probably not on the scene yet, so parent is nil.

Comment: can you show a screen shot or draw a diagram of your sks files or try to better explain how many reference nodes there are? It is unclear if you have one reference node or 2 and if the second reference node also has a reference node??

Comment: Edited for clarity -- would appreciate some help, thanks.